Python dataframe Selecting specific number of rows from column 1 and all rows from column 2
"EDIT: This is NOT a duplicate of the other question. Stop flagging this!".
I have two columns in excel sheet that looks like this

I want to iterate in python (using dataframe if possible) to produce multiple excel sheets where my excel files would look like this
File_1 Output (Column 1 will get 10 cities, column 2 will have all persons)

File_2 Output (Column 1 will get the next 10 cities, column 2 will have all persons without any change)

The for loop will continue to iterate until all the rows are done.
Let's say if I have 105 cities in column 1, the code will generate 11 output files where the last file will only have 5 cities in column 1.
I have tried to use the following code
rows_per_file = 10
n_chunks = PC // rows_per_file


for i in range(n_chunks):
    start = i*rows_per_file
    stop = (i+1) * rows_per_file
    sub_df= df(df.iloc[start:stop,0],0)
    sub_df2=df(df.iloc[0:UC,1],1)
    sub_df3= sub_df+sub_df2
    sub_df3.to_excel(f"test-{i}.xlsx", sheet_name="sheet")

But it gives me all data in single column and slices my 2nd column to 10 person too instead of all 26 person.
I have tried different ways but haven't been able to figure out.
Any help is appreciated :)


you have several options, such as: for i, g in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//10): g.to_csv(f'file_{i}.csv')

If this is not what you want, please be explicit, provide a [mre] (as text/code, not images) and without ..., and provide the exact (and complete) matching expected output. You might want to take groups of only 3/4 rows as a example.

@mozway as usual brilliant solution!

Also you can add this to your question.
"EDIT: This is NOT a duplicate of the other question. Stop flagging this!". As it is not  a duplicate because you are also iterating the second column, not just splitting dataframe to equal chucks.

@mozway please don't flag my question.
I am trying to keep the 2nd column as is, without slicing it. But the iloc slices my 2nd column also. I am trying to find answer to this.
The link you provided does not have specific solution to the problem I am asking for.
I have tried different options from their code too!
As I am learning python, I appreciate your help on this :)

@User646972 I'll be happy to reopen/answer the question, but please provide a fully reproducible minimal example (see here for pointers on how to do so). Unless starting from an excel sheet is critical, please provide a DataFrame constructor of the input and the exact matching expected output(s). Without a MRE and a clear logic, we cannot determine that is it not a duplicate.

@mozway, yes you are right, without DataFrame and expected output(s) it is hard to figure out how to help.

import pandas as pd
cities = [f"City{i}" for i in range(1,101)]
people = [f"Person{i}" for i in range(1,26+1)]
rows_per_file = 10

list_cities = [cities[i:i + len(people)] for i in range(0, len(cities), rows_per_file)]
for c in list_cities:
    pd.DataFrame({"cities":c,"people":people[:len(c)]}).to_csv(f"From {c[0]} to {c[-1]}.csv")

Outputs  files:
From City1 to City26.csv
From City11 to City36.csv
From City21 to City46.csv
From City31 to City56.csv
From City41 to City66.csv
From City51 to City76.csv
From City61 to City86.csv
From City71 to City96.csv
From City81 to City100.csv
From City91 to City100.csv

Output of "From City1 to City26.csv".



cities
people




City1
Person1


City2
Person2


City3
Person3


City4
Person4


City5
Person5


City6
Person6


City7
Person7


City8
Person8


City9
Person9


City10
Person10


City11
Person11


City12
Person12


City13
Person13


City14
Person14


City15
Person15


City16
Person16


City17
Person17


City18
Person18


City19
Person19


City20
Person20


City21
Person21


City22
Person22


City23
Person23


City24
Person24


City25
Person25


City26
Person26



Output of "From City91 to City100.csv"



cities
people




City91
Person1


City92
Person2


City93
Person3


City94
Person4


City95
Person5


City96
Person6


City97
Person7


City98
Person8


City99
Person9


City100
Person10




Thank you for your answer, But you may have not read the question correctly. I have 100 cities in col 1 and 26 person in column 2. And how I want the desired output file is also given as image :) Thanks for taking the time in answering.

I've updated my answer, but I don't think it still answers your question, as I still don't quite get the final picture.

Thanks again, But your code is only creating the input file that I already have. Could you please check the next 2 images on how I want my output files?  :)

Thank you so much. But the code you gave does not keep the 2nd column as is. It slices through the 2nd column too. I am trying to slice only the 1st column and append the 2nd column as is to each csv file. I really appreciate your help :)

Updated once again. =)
Hopefully it is right this time.
